# "A und dessen/deren B"

Tags: genitive, demonstrative-pronoun

Wenn ich folgenden Satz habe:

> Die Entwicklung eines Autos und dessen/deren Evaluation.

Worauf bezieht sich das *dessen/deren*? Bezieht es sich auf das Auto oder auf die Evaluation?

Ich finde nämlich mit Google beide Varianten:

- [und dessen Evaluation](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22und%20dessen%20Evaluation%22)
- [und deren Evaluation](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22und%20deren%20Evaluation%22)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ob es *dessen* oder *deren* heißen muss, hängt davon ab, auf was Du Dich beziehst.
*Dessen* heißt es bei sächlichen und männlichen Dingen *(das Auto, der Wagen)* und *deren* heißt es bei weiblichen Dingen (*die Entwicklung*). Daher ist es bei Deinem Beispiel leicht:

*Dessen* bezieht sich auf *das* Auto und *deren* auf *die* Entwicklung.

Bei „Die Entwicklung einer Kutsche und deren Evaluation“ kann man es nicht sagen, weil beides weiblich ist *(die Entwicklung, die Kutsche).*

Weitere Beispiele:

- > *Die Entwicklung eines Wagens und deren Evaluation*

  → *deren* bezieht sich auf *die* Entwicklung. Es bedeutet, dass die Entwicklung evaluiert wird (nicht der Wagen). Beispielsweise wird evaluiert (=bewertet), ob die Entwicklung/der Entwicklungs-Prozess bestimmten Anforderungen an die Qualitätssicherung genügte oder ISO-Normen entsprach.
- > *Die Entwicklung eines Wagens und dessen Evaluation*

  → *dessen* bezieht sich auf *den* Wagen. Es bedeutet, dass der Wagen bewertet wird, z.B. ob er das gewünschte Platzangebot oder den erwarteten Benzinverbrauch hat.

Comment: Wenn ich eine Evaluation für den Wagen mache, nehme ich dessen?

Comment: @user1091344 Genau. _Die Entwicklung eines Wagens und dessen Evaluation_ bedeutet, dass Du den Wagen evaluierst. Es ist gleichbedeutend mit _Die Entwicklung **und die Evaluation** eines Wagens_.

Comment: Das heißt im Umkehrschluss, dass der Satz mit "deren" unvollständig ist, oder?

Comment: @user1091344 Nein. _Die Entwicklung eines Wagens und deren Evaluation_ ist absolut vollständig. Ich habe meine Antwort ergänzt.